# Methods of Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ Multiple Choice Question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Which of the following techniques for evaluating limits cannot be used to show $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

$a:$ The Squeeze Theorem

$b:$ L'Hôpital's Rule

$c:$ Using the graph

$d:$ Factoring/Diving Out.

I want to ask is the answer $d$? I'm unsure whether it is $c$ or $d$.

Comment: Should be D. The graph is visual evidence of the limit at zero.

Comment: It's likely D. *However*, you could expand the series for $\sin x$ and then divide out the $x$ to show the limit. That's not factoring though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option $a$ works because we can squeeze the limit using
$$ \cos(x)\le\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le1.$$
I'll leave this to you, ask a question if it's unclear.

Option $b$ works if you are granted that $\frac{d\sin(x)}{dx}:=\cos(x)$. If not, then this is incorrect because it is circular reasoning: see Arthur's comment. If we are granted the definition of the derivative of $\sin(x),$ apply L'Hôpital's rule to the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Differentiating top and bottom we get 
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)}{1}=1.$$
Option $c$ works. Consider the graph: [image]

This indicates the limit as $x\to0$ is $1$.

Option $d$ however, does not work. We can't factor anything out of $\sin(x)$ such that a cancellation occurs. You can verify this.

Comment: Option (b) is usually considered not working: In order to calculate the derivative for $\sin x$, you get
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h) - \sin x}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sin x\cos h + \cos x \sin h-\sin x}{h}\\
\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\cos x\color{red}{\frac{\sin h}{h}} + \sin x \frac{\cos h - 1}{h}\right)
$$See that red term there? Using L'Hopital to calculate this limit is a circular argument.

Comment: Yeah that's true. But in the case of most Calculus classes, it's incorrectly allowed. I'm assuming that's the case here. That is, most of the time, it's given as a definition that the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$.

Comment: In that case I would say the answer is (b) _and_ (d). It's not like the question is excluding several correct answers.

Comment: I agree. OP asked as though there was supposed to be one incorrect answer. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: option c) is nonsense, as with any claim to compute a limit by looking at the graph. Option d) may work just fine, if you define $\sin(x)$ by its Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have enough rep. to comment yet. So, I will post this as an answer*. I think you can use all methods. Using **taylor expansion of sin(x)** about zero, you can factor out an x from all terms, cancelling it with the one in the denominator, which will give the answer as 1 too. But I think your course has not yet covered taylor expansions. So, you could go with d. Please feel free to comment on my answer.